# situado "a" o "en"

Tags: preposiciones

I have a problem with the preposición of the adjective "situado"
I stumbled across the two sentences:

1. "Su sede central es un edificio de tres plantas situado **al** sur de España"

But meanwhile, I also found:

2. "Libia es un país situado **en** el desierto"

Could anyone explain why we use different preposiciones in 1. and 2.?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to the site, Mike!  Do please keep in mind that there's more wiggle room for preposition choice than for some other things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase *estar situado* usually goes with *en*, as *en* usually denotes location and *a* usually denotes movement. For example, one would say

- La sede está situada [*en la calle Comedias/en Málaga/en España*].

But expressions with the cardinal points (*norte, sur, este, oeste*) are an exception, where *al sur de* can be used to mean *(in the) south of*, even if it implies no movement. As explained by [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/al-norte-en-el-norte-2/), *al sur de* can mean either "south of, but outside" or "south of, but inside". In the second case (which is the one in your example), using *en el sur de* is also valid and even preferred to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

situado a usually means that whatever is located roughly, more or less... example 'situado a tres metros de la playa', even if it says 3m, it is a rough estimate.

en usually means that the indication is more precise